# Why Integer("09") throwing exception in ruby while Integer("07") works pretty well?

Tags: ruby

I am using ruby 1.9.3

Why Integer("09") throws "invalid value for Integer exception" in ruby while Integer("07") works pretty well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because a leading zero is a common convention for octal (“base 8”) notation. There is no `9` digit in octal, therefore it is a syntax error to use one.

If you had written `Integer("014")`, you would have gotten the number 12. (Therefore, do not use leading zeroes if you do not intend the octal notation.)

Comment: To clarify, this isn't restricted to ruby. In Python, for example: `print 0177` outputs `127`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid To tell the truth, I answered this question without  having using ruby for anything other than copy-pasted snippets. Octal was apparently particularly useful on the PDP-11, and the first C compiler was for the PDP-11, I think. That may be why C has a lighter syntax for octal than for hexadecimal. It must have spread from there to other languages.

Comment: You got me convinced with that Pascal.

Comment: Note that `"09".to_i` and `"014".to_i` will both give the correct results.

Comment: C is patient zero for all the modern languages with this "feature", but it actuallyinherited the syntax from B/BCPL. Interestingly enough, the earlier languages would happily accept 8 and 9 in octal literals, while still using 8s for the place values, so e.g. 088 was a legal literal with the value of decimal 72.

Answer (score 3):

If you start it with a 0 it thinks its octal. 9 is not a valid octal digit!